# Vim higlight subsection

Tags: vim, highlight, vi

In Vim I want misspelled words in code strings be highlighted differently than misspelled words outside code strings.

Basically, if it it a `String` element then I want:

```
:hi SpellBad ctermfg=0 "Backgroud colour
```

But if it isn't a `String` element then I want:

```
:hi SpellBad ctermfg=7 "White
```

How can I best accomplish this?

Comment: I think your problem is not possible to solve without programming. Spell mechanism allows enable or disable highlighting misspelled words based on other highlighting rules (see `:help spell-syntax`).  But different colors for misspelled word based on context is not possible IMHO. But well vim is mighty and it does not mean that the possibility does not exist if I do not know it. So I did not write a response but wrote only a comment.